# java.sql.SQLException :no value specified for parameter 6

Tags: java, netbeans

when press update button it shows:

> "java.sql.SQLException:parameter out of range(1>number of parameters,which is 0)".

```
 private void updateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/smakdb","root","kisal400");    
        String sql="Update itemk set name=?,type=?, buying price=?, selling price=?,description=? where itemid=?";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        pst.setString(1, name2.getText());
            String value=type2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                pst.setString(2,value);
        pst.setDouble(3,Double.parseDouble(buying2.getText()));
        pst.setDouble(4,Double.parseDouble(selling2.getText()));
        pst.setString(5,descript2.getText());

        pst.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "updated!!!");
        conn.close();

        }catch(Exception e){

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
```

Comment: Your SQL appears to contain column names with spaces in them (e.g. buying price.) Even if this is allowable it's hardly recommended practice. You would probably have to have put quotes around those column names in the SQL...

Comment: `no value specified for parameter 6` - The message is clear, you need to specify the 6th parameter `itemid`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993563/java-sql-sqlexception-no-value-specified-for-parameter-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 6 question mark in the query, why not set the 6th parameter value?

You need set `itemid` as well.

Comment: edited.now it shows" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException.you have an error  in your sql syntax."

Comment: Of course, it is wrong. `Update itemk set name=?,type=?, buying price=?, selling price=?,description=? where itemid=?`  You are trying to say `buying_price` and `selling_price` right?

Comment: @kisalriff  don't forget choose mine as answer:)

Answer (score 0):

In String sql you have six parameters "?" and once set five parameters.

Comment: edited.now it shows" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException.you have an error  in your sql syntax."